# ¿Hay alguna manera de determinar si existe una coleccion?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

¿Hay alguna manera de determinar si existe una colección dentro de una base de datos?

Comment: coleccion o conexion??, por cierto, recomiendo dar un paseo por el [tour] y de paso leer [ask].

Comment: Colección. La idea es verificar si existe, si existe que la cree y si no que no haga nada me explico?

Comment: No es porque tu pregunta no se entienda, es porque según entiendo en la comunidad no es valida este tipo de preguntas.

Comment: No necesitas hacer esa verificación. MongoDB usualmente crea la colección si la misma no existe. Sin embargo, puedes consultar el nombre de todas las colecciones existentes en una DB y decidir de acuerdo al resultado de dicha consulta. Debes consultar la documentación del *driver* específico para tu aplicación. En el caso de Node, puedes usar [`listCollections()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#listCollections) seguido de [`toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/CommandCursor.html#toArray) para obtener dicha lista. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a MongoDB consultar si existe un dato en la base de datos puedes usar el operador **$exists**

Te colocare un ejemplo:

Si nosotros queremos saber si existe una colección que contenga **a** con un valor **true** realizamos la siguiente consulta:

```
db.records.find( { a: { $exists: true } } )
```